# Set integer 'variable' using result of NSString

Tags: ios, nested, integer, uiswitch

I'm using a single action to handle 10 UISwitches by sending a tag value to it. I have a number of integers initialised when launched thus;

int switch_1 = 0;
int switch_2 = 0; etc

When a particular switch is switched on, I want to set the integer to the corresponding integer 'variable' with a 1

So, if switch 2 with tag 2 is turned on, it puts a '1' in the corresponding int 'switch_2' as an integer.

I am getting a string with the right name via 'stringWithFormat' by appending the tag value but don't know how to write the 1 to the corresponding integer variable from it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Essentially, I want to write an integer to a 'variable' name with the same name as the generated string value.

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code related to it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array where each index represents your switch, so it would be like following:

```
int swtichArray[10] = {0}; // if you have 10 switches
```

While in your action where you handling action of multiple buttons, you could do that:

```
switchArray[tagOfSwitch] = 1; // if tags are staring from 0 onwards 9
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Many, many thanks!!!!!

Comment: Always glad to help :)